# TactionbarSherlock - having trouble implementing the list navigation

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to work from the ActionbarSherlock example for adding a list navigation. In the example, there is some code like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.list_navigation);
    mSelected = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    mLocations = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations);

    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
}
```

and that seems to be it. So I am confused where I can add the titles for the navigation. And also it references

```
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            context, R.array.locations, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
```

and my code is not aware of R.array.locations and gives a syntax error. But that R.array.locations is not in the examples.  Should I create a separate file for it in my layout directory?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your compile error: Did you create an array resource called "locations"?

/res/values/arrays

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="locations">
        <item>Foo</item>
        <item>Bar</item>
        <item>Baz</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Regarding providing special "tiles" for the dropdown: Even though it's called "List Navigation", what you are actually seeing in the Action Bar (both the native one and ActionBarSherlock's) is a Spinner. So you can give it any SpinnerAdapter and it will use that.

If you aren't familiar with adapters, I highly recommend you [watch this video](http://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70). The only difference between an adapter for a ListView and an adapter for a Spinner is the getDropDownView() method, which creates the views that appear in the dropdown menu (where getView() provides the view shown in the spinner content area).

Answer (score 1):

> But that R.array.locations is not in the examples

[It sure is](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/res/values/arrays.xml#L15-L21).

```
<string-array name="locations">
    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Email</item>
    <item>Calendar</item>
    <item>Browser</item>
    <item>Clock</item>
</string-array>
```